# Android Twitter4j

Tags: android, twitter4j

I want to create a application where user can login with twitter account and whatever activity he does (depending on other cases) should be tweeted.

Now since twitter has removed basic authentication how to achieve this ????

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You could check this OAuth TUT: http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/sending-a-tweet-t54389.html Shows how to use Twitter4J with source files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use third party libraries to perform OAuth. See the following threads to get some insight on OAuth and how to perform 3 legged authentication:
1. [Some questions about OAuth and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189875/some-questions-about-oauth-and-android)
2. [OAuth on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121329/oauth-callback-on-android)
3. [OAuth + TWitter on Android with code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199357/oauth-twitter-on-android-callback-fails)

Hope that helps...

Comment: i will check it out ........... I have successfully tweeted with oAuth, but also want other users to be authenticated....... Thanks for the response......... I am checking the links........

Comment: thanks the links helped me a bit , got a portion of it working.......... Thanks again